# Arules in R: A very high measure for lift

Tags: r, apriori, arules

Running Apriori with the Arules package, generates rules with very high lift.

For example:

`A -> B support=0.0023 confidence=0.6832 lift=28.02`

(min_support=0.002 and min_conf=0.2)

In some rules, the lift is as high as 250! I have seen people discuss a lift greater than 1 (most of them <5), but I'm wondering how I can interpret these rules with very high lift values.

Comment: Your support isn't very high. How many observations actually fall into that support?

Comment: Completely 0ff-topic. No coding content. No data example.

Comment: About 530 observations. The data is quite sparse, @Dason.

Comment: With 530 observations,  `support=0.0023` would mean that the rule would only apply to a single data point!

Comment: Sorry I think my comment was misleading. Total number of transactions is about 200k. 530 was the number of observations with that rule (i.e. cnt in the rule)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lift measure stands for how likely item Y is purchased when item X is purchased, while controlling for how popular item Y is:

support(X,Y)/(support(X)*support(Y)).

Generally, a lift value greater than 1 means that item Y is likely to be bought if item X is bought, while a value less than 1 means that item Y is unlikely to be bought if item X is bought. If you had a huge dataset, that would be interesting, however, with your small dataset and support, this is just nothing. Check here for a nice illustrative [answer](https://algobeans.com/2016/04/01/association-rules-and-the-apriori-algorithm/):

Answer (score 2):

You set the minimum support count (apriori in `arules` reports this) to

> 0.002 * 530 transactions = 1.06

This means that every rule with items happening together only once by chance will be considered leading to many spurious rules with very high lift. For example, if two items, x and y, each occur only once in the dataset but happen to be in the same transaction then you get for your dataset a lift of

> lift(x -> y) = supp(x, y)/(supp(x) * supp(y)) = (1/580 / (1/580 * 1/580)) = 580.

However, the rule is not very useful since it happened just once by chance.

The following paper contains a detailed treatment of this and other problems with possible solutions:

[Michael Hahsler and Kurt Hornik. New probabilistic interest measures for association rules. Intelligent Data Analysis, 11(5):437-455, 2007](http://michael.hahsler.net/research/hyperConfidence_IDA2007/hyperConfidence.pdf)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the 530 was the number of transactions _satisfying_ the support. I have about 200k transactions.

Comment: In this case, it means that the items are highly correlated. Sometimes the data generating process creates highly correlated items and the question is then if the correlation is interesting for the application.

Comment: Thanks, the paper was very useful.